# Main window doesn't update immediately when I add widgets

Tags: c++, qt, layout

In `button_clicked()` in mainwindow.cpp, I want to add a label to a horizontal layout every 300 ms.

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
       QPixmap i1 (":/notes/pic/a.jpg");
       QLabel *label = new QLabel();
       label->setPixmap(i1);
       ui->horizontalLayout_4->addWidget(label);
       QThread::msleep(300);
    }
```

But the main window does not refresh or update itself. After the for loop finishes, all labels are added at the same time. But I want to add that label exactly when I call  `ui->horizontalLayout_4->addWidget(label);`

Comment: [You already asked essentially the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427608/qt-adding-widgets-to-horizontal-layout-step-by-step?rq=1) The top answer is correct, you need to use something like a timer. Never sleep on the main thread, this freezes the UI.

Comment: when i use a timer, yes they are added in every 300 ms but it is still adds the labels after for loop finishes. i need to add the labels when i call `ui->horizontalLayout_4->addWidget(label);`.

Comment: You need to add the widgets one at a time in a slot that is called on timeout of your timer. You cannot code a loop that sleeps directly. (Well, you _could_, but you really shouldn't.) The top answer to your other question explains this already.